# Which SQL Query execute faster

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the two queries, client statistics in SQL Server Management Studio shows that the second query has faster total execution time. Can anyone tell me why the second query is faster?

```
SELECT MERCHANT_NO,
(SELECT CASE WHEN CITY IS NULL OR CITY='' THEN m.CITY  
 ELSE 
    COALESCE((SELECT c.CITY
     FROM CODE_CITY c
     WHERE m.CITY=c.CODE_CITY_ID
    ), m.CITY)    
  END) AS CITY,
(SELECT CASE WHEN STATE IS NULL OR STATE='' THEN m.STATE  
 ELSE 
    COALESCE((SELECT s.STATE
     FROM CODE_STATE s
     WHERE m.STATE=s.CODE_STATE_ID
    ), m.STATE)    
  END) AS STATE,
(SELECT MERCHANT_CAT_DESC FROM MERCHANT_CAT mc WHERE mc.MERCHANT_CAT_ID=m.MERCHANT_CAT_ID) AS MERCHANT_CAT_DESC 
FROM MERCHANT m 
WHERE 1=1

SELECT MERCHANT_NO, 
(SELECT CASE WHEN t.CITY IS NULL OR t.CITY='' THEN m.CITY 
  ELSE 
     t.CITY 
  END AS CITY
 FROM(
      SELECT 
       CASE WHEN CITY IS NULL OR CITY='' THEN '' 
          ELSE 
             (SELECT c.CITY
               FROM CODE_CITY c
               WHERE merc.CITY=c.CODE_CITY_ID
              )      
          END AS CITY
          FROM MERCHANT merc
          WHERE merc.MERCHANT_NO=m.MERCHANT_NO
) t ) AS CITY_DESC,  
(SELECT CASE WHEN cs.STATE IS NULL OR cs.STATE='' THEN m.STATE 
  ELSE 
     cs.STATE 
  END AS STATE
 FROM(
      SELECT 
       CASE WHEN STATE IS NULL OR STATE='' THEN '' 
          ELSE 
             (SELECT s.STATE
               FROM CODE_STATE s
               WHERE merc.STATE=s.CODE_STATE_ID
              )      
          END AS STATE
          FROM MERCHANT merc
          WHERE merc.MERCHANT_NO=m.MERCHANT_NO
) cs ) AS STATE_DESC, 
(SELECT MERCHANT_CAT_DESC FROM MERCHANT_CAT mc WHERE mc.MERCHANT_CAT_ID=m.MERCHANT_CAT_ID) AS MERCHANT_CAT_DESC 
FROM MERCHANT m 
WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: This would be a good time to learn how to use `EXPLAIN`, which will probably reveal more details about the two queries than any answer you might receive.

Comment: You will get even faster execution time when you convert both of your queries from correlated sub-queries to inner join

Comment: turn on execution plan and run both queries , you can see for yourself

Comment: You are not using COALESCE data in second query. How much data is there for which you are testing these queries?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using **COALESCE** data in second query. So only it can be more faster than first query.